# How to set "Total" in footer at Yajra dataTable to get "total" of one or multiple columns in every page or at lest at the end

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

There is a problem at Yajra DataTable to showing sum of some column data. How can I resolve this for Yajra?  (I want actual view of total- like marked position)
[image: I want actual view of total- like marked position]

Answer (score 1):

the process is bit long, first you need to add footer to your table, then after the column array objects add "footerCallback" key with callback function, then convert the column you want to sum into integer. see example [image]
[enter link description here](https://phppot.com/jquery/calculate-sum-total-of-datatables-column-using-footer-callback/)

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for Datatables'  drawCallback() function - this will run after each time the table is drawn (on page load, and after it is filtered down) and will perform a specific action.

In this instance you would want to sum the relevant column using something along these lines :

```
var sum = $('#yourTable').DataTable().column(4).data().sum();
```

and then just use jQuery to write the value to the relevant span or div as you would normally :

```
$('#yourTotalBox').html(sum);
```

Comment: I tried this one, but this is not working with yajra (with nfyOM). When I use the predefined table id 'dataTableBuilder', the output result is not showing, but no errors.

Comment: What if you console.log("Hello") in the drawCallback() function - does it log? ie. is that function firing, it's just unable to find the datatable you're trying to sum the column for?

Comment: I'm getting the alert/console, but extra footer is not adding. my query and callback function are using in app\DataTables\MyTable.php -  throgh  
"
public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
       ->parameters(........
"

Comment: You want your callback function to be client-side, not server side. More info https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback